# How to ping a device from a server and get a response with the device's location when the app is in the background using React Native

Tags: react-native

We're trying to build an app that can track the location of the device on-demand. So admins could send a ping signal and get back the current location of the device. Sort of like (find my phone). The functionality should work even if the app is in the background, when the device is locked, and even be available after a device restart without having to open the app first.
We're building the app using React Native and we were looking at some options for background services and push notifications but none seem to satisfy our needs. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested with this paid solution: https://www.transistorsoft.com/shop/products/react-native-background-geolocation

Comment: This looks promising, thank you. But as far as I can tell, it still won't allow me to pull the current location immediately when requested but rather have to rely on continuously logging the location data.